# Getting filename that was used on setGraphic()

Tags: javafx-8

I am currently working on a puzzle type of app on javaFX. I created a 2d array of buttons that I used `setGraphic` to insert the pictures. I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve the filename that I used on `setGraphic` so I can compare to pictures together. I know there is a `getGraphic` method but that returns random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setGraphic` takes a `Node`, not a `Image` object; I assume you use `ImageView`s as graphics.

There is no way to retrieve the file name from an `Image` object since you need not pass a url to the `Image` constructor but are also allowed to pass a `InputStream`. `InputStream` does not provide any information about it's source and `Image` also doesn't.

To get the file path from a image you need to store the information yourself, e.g.:

```
private final Map<Image, String> imageFileNames = new IdentityHashMap<>();

public Image loadImage(String filename) throws MalformedURLException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
    imageFileNames.put(image, filename);
    return image;
}

public String getImageFileName(Image image) {
    return imageFileNames.get(image);
}
```

With a node containing a `ImageView` as a graphic, you could do something like this:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) node.getGraphic();
Image img = view.getImage();
String fileName = getImageFieldName(img);
```

Possibly adding null checks, if the `graphic` and/or the `image` can be `null`.

---

You could also the data in the node's `userData` or `properties` if you like:

**Storing**

```
File file = new File(filename);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
imageView.setUserData(filename);
```

**Retrieving**

```
String filename = (String) node.getGraphic().getUserData();
```